# Does OpenGL have preshaders?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl, shader

My question is kinda simple but i cant find it in the web.
Does OpenGL / OpenGL ES have preshaders like DirectX?

so that you can write things like

```
mat4 wvpMat = worldMat * viewMat * projMat;
gl_Position = wvpMat * position;
```

and it will compute the wvpMat only once in the preshader.
Or is this not supported and you should make it on the CPU instead?

see Riemers example for XNA:

[image: XNA with preshaders]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenGL [defines several shader stages](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview):

1. vertex shader: runs first for all points you wish to draw
2. optional tesselation with 2 shaders: a control shader to specify how to tesselate and a evaluation shader to do the actual tesselation
3. optional geometry shader: emit a variable amount of primitive per drawn primitive
4. fragment shader: runs per fragment

The driver is allowed to optimize each of these as needed when linking the program together, which may include generating a preshader. However, it is implementation-defined.

Comment: so that means based on the driver it may generate a preshader? so to be on the save side i should do it on the CPU

Comment: @HellGate No, to be on the *sane* side you should measure the timings and compare with expected outcomes.

Comment: That is not true, you measurement is only valid for your specific platfrom, driver version, etc. and there are many different configurations where things might get slowed down. I usually generate my model-view-projection matrix on the CPU, it's zero penalty (3 4x4 matrix multiplications take near-zero time) and it's only done once for every (possibly huge) batch of geometry.

Comment: when i have time i will try to profile it on my platform but yea doing it on the CPU takes not much time and as [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206299(v=vs.85).aspx#PreShaders_Improve_Performance) says it does the preshader on the CPU as well. its more like a how you are used to write it thing and i find i handy having the seperate mat4's in the shader

Comment: You can also look at advice from different vendors. Imagination for instance (perhaps relevant for the opengl-es tag) states that "The PowerVR shader compiler is able to extract calculations based on  uniforms from the shader and perform these calculations once per draw call."

Comment: Nice summary. Note tessellation and geometry shaders are only on desktop OpenGL, not OpenGL ES.

Answer (score 2):

No, current OpenGL versions don't have something like preshaders. Personally I don't see actual benefit in having them, but other people might like them so much, that upcoming OpenGL versions might get them.

Comment: hmmm thanks for the answer even if its not the answer i wanted to hear :P. guess i have to rewrite some stuff then

Comment: @HellGate Before you rewrite anything, check if the drivers don't actually optimize the instructions. The whole concept of preshaders bases on the idea of manual optimization vs machine optimization, and the latter tends to be vastly superior nowadays.

Comment: @HellGate: Like Bartek told you, drivers have a lot leeway to optimize things. The major difference to Direct3D is, that in Direct3D the HLSL code is compiled to an intermediary, which you then ship. It's this intermediary that implements the preshaders. In OpenGL however you ship with the GLSL which gets compiled at runtime. In the beginning GLSL compilers were horrible. Nowadays they've become quite good. Some OpenGL implementations like Mesa actually make use of existing compiler infrastructure, like LLVM (the same compiler framework also used for clang).

Comment: @HellGate: So good GLSL compilers will detect expressions evaluating to identical values for all input and optimize that. It used to be a performance problem with NVidia, because their compiler was a bit overzealous and recompiled the shader whenever a uniform value got changed, but that's no longer a problem now.

Comment: @datenwolf: thanks for the info but i cant really tell if my the compiler for my platform is a "good" one. So i better do it myself so i know what is happening and as said before, the dx9 compiler does the preshader on the CPU as well so the result should be the same just not automated